# Profile pictures not working on my playstore app

Tags: java, android, flutter

My app is now live on Google play store, but it doesn't show any profile image again. And shared preference for the token is not working. Please what's the issue, does it mean that Google altered it? The local one is working

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution in the GitHub issues here github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/497. Turns out it is a proguard issue with the sqflite library that CachedNetworkImage uses. The solution, until they fix it in the library, is to add a the default proguard file to the build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true // Add these lines
            shrinkResources true // Add these lines
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt') // Add these lines
        }
    }
```